# I don´t know how to change my program so that i can see the ten largest files

Tags: java, file

I need to program some statistics, like Count files etc.
But I have a problem with one of the tasks: 
Write code to identify the 10 largest Files.

My Problem is that I don´t know how to get started. I have code to get the largest file. But how i can get the ten largest files ? 
Here is one class that shows the largest file.

```
@Override
public String getDescription() {
   return "find largest file";
}

@Override
public void printResults(List<File> files) {
    File largest = files.get(0);
    for (File f : files)
    if (f.length() > largest.length())
    largest = f;
    System.out.println("Largest file: " + largest.getName() + " (" + largest.length() + " bytes)");
}
```

Comment: What about sorting the list by file size and printing the first 10 elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the files by file size and get the first 10 elements. Note that you will get strange results with this code if any of your files are really big:

```java
@Override
public void printResults(List<File> files) {
    files.sort((file1,file2) -> (int)(file1.length()-file2.length())); // This will NOT work correctly if any of the files are over 2.7 GB in size.
    List<File> largest = files.subList(0, files.size() > 10 ? 10 : files.size());
    System.out.println("Largest files:");
    for(File file : largest) {
        System.out.println(file.getName() + " (" + file.length() + " bytes)");
    }
}
```

Comment: okay i understand the Code i think. But why is there a Question mark between 10 ? I didn´t see it, i think, before in the codes and i will really understand everything.

Comment: This prevents a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` of the file list does not have 10 elements. Alternatively you can use `files.subList(0, Math.min(files.size(), 10));`

Comment: @AnGeL think of it as a compact `if` statement to assign a value to a variable or return said value. `if(condition){x=value1;}else{x=value2;}` becomes `x=condition ? value1 : value2`. Likewise, `if(condition){return value1;}else{return value2;}` becomes `return condition ? value1 : value2`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Java Stream API to sort and limit the file list:

```
files.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(File::length).reversed())
        .limit(10)
        .forEach(f -> System.out.println(f.getName() + " (" + f.length() + " bytes)"));
```